# Problem with query to get posts category in a wordpress theme - would like to see only "Upcoming events category"

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to display only a certain category of posts on my WordPress theme page. I have edited the page to include a simple query. the query is meant to get the post category before the loop starts. In theory, it should work, but not working at all.

I tried the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package mothertongues
 */

get_header();
?>

    <main id="primary" class="site-main">

        <?php
            query_posts('category name=Upcoming event');
        if ( have_posts() ) :

            if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) :
                ?>
                <header>
                    <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                </header>
                <?php
            endif;

            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

            endwhile;

            the_posts_navigation();

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

This is the line I tried to use to select only that specific category:

```
query_posts('category name=Upcoming event');
```

If anyone can help me it would be super appreciated.

Comment: If anyone could help me, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try using `pre_get_posts` hook to modify the main query on the homepage to only fetch posts from the "Upcoming event".

Remove **query_posts('category name=Upcoming event');** from your template code and try adding the following code in your theme's **functions.php**

```
function custom_modify_main_query( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'category_name', 'Upcoming event' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_modify_main_query' );
```